# How to change the down arrow in a submenu in element-plus

Tags: vuejs3, submenu, element-plus

I'm working on a website using vuejs3 and element-plus, there are supposed to be some submenus but when you use

```
<el-menu
    :default-active="activeIndex"
    class="el-menu-demo"
    mode="horizontal"
    @select="handleSelect"
  >
 <el-sub-menu class="submenu" index="1">
                            <template #title>1. Introductions</template>
                            <el-menu-item index="1-1">item one</el-menu-item>
                            <el-menu-item index="1-2">item two</el-menu-item>
                            <el-menu-item index="1-3">item three</el-menu-item>
                          </el-sub-menu>
<el-menu>
```

it gives a default drop down arrow which when clicked will display the elements in the submenu and there is no direct access to change how the arrow should look as in using your own arrow style.

If you know how I can change the arrow please help me out. Thank you

[This is how the default arrow looks like and i want to change it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqPle.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
expand-close-icon && expand-open-icon
```

Comment: can you please explain it a bit for me.@Snow_yrsw

Comment: ohh sorry，I would know if you want add your customize class for the arrow icon or you want change the icon about the "arrow icon @coochie"